# Easy way to create services on HDP cluster

Tags: service, bigdata, hdp

We have a company with a HDP 2.6.4 cluster and an outsource / offshore team that handles different ops tasks. Due to quite strict data access policies, that cannot have access to quite a few datasets. However, we do need them to be able to 24/7 monitor and (ideally) execute different jobs.

So I'm in position as someone in Big data team to enable them to do so, but without access to data. Not being sure what would HDP 2.6 have to offer, I do know that there are certain tools that enable devs to develop all kind of API endpoints, which could then be mapped to different ETL jobs / shell scripts etc.
Would this be optimal approach from an architectural standpoint?

I was thinking of getting us something like Dreamfactory, but opensource and something I can run on premise. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DreamFactory can generate REST APIs for a multitude of databases, among them MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and MongoDB. Along with the API, DreamFactory will also auto-generate an extensive set of interactive Swagger documentation for your API. Are you looking to connect databases?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was under impression DF can do more. Still looking for a solution...